# Using pandas, how can I find out if my customer made a purchase last month or two months ago?

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python and new to pandas. Of course, if my project used exact dates, I could easily do this, but unfortunately, the date type is a little different, and as you can see, the sign 08 is after the year 1401, which means it is the eighth month of the year 1401.

[image]

I currently know that these 3 customers have bought from me this month. But I want to know if these 3 customers bought from me in the previous month or two months ago? If they do, I will give them a discount.
Of course, I should also say that the number 08 is not always fixed, but it could be 09 in the next month. I just want to know if they bought from me 1 month ago or not?

According to the picture, now only Sara should get a discount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the purchase date to an integer and calculate the number of months from there.

For instance, you have the purchase month `1901/07` and you want to know in `1901/08` how many months the last purchase took place. So you convert both values to integers and subtract them (`190108 - 190107 = 1`).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'customer': ['david', 'sara'], 'date': ['1901/03', '1901/07']})

# Manually setting the reference month (190108 for Year 1901 and Month 08)
df['months'] = 190108 - df['date'].replace('/', '', regex=True).astype(int)

# Check if eligible for discount
df['discount'] = df['months'].isin([1, 2])
```

|  | customer | date | months | discount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | david | 1901/03 | 5 | False |
| 1 | sara | 1901/07 | 1 | True |

To compare with today's month you could to the following:

```
df['months'] = int(pd.Timestamp.now().strftime('%Y%m'))\
                - df['date'].replace('/', '', regex=True).astype(int)
```

Comment: i have question what is 190108 ?

Comment: `190108` is an integer version of `1901/08` to check if `1901/07` is a month ago. I used the year 1901 instead of 1401 because some python function don't work with dates very long ago.

Comment: I updated the answer to explain the logic a bit more. Let me know if you have any additional questions.